# At what point should I compile the ts files of a library package?

Tags: typescript, build, repository

I am developing a nodejs package on typescript. I don't put the compiled js files in the repository. On the one hand it is correct, I need to keep in the repository only source files. In addition to that, storing compiled files in VCS creates artifact problems. On the other hand it's inconvenient - when updating project, which uses my package, it takes extra time to compile its ts files. However, I see that other packages written in typescript contain compiled js files in the repository. Do they just commit the js files or use some post-commit hooks or something like that?

What are the best practices you use to solve this problem?

Comment: A package may be written in TypeScript but has to be released as JavaScript (possibly with TypeScript definition files) because JavaScript is the runnable language. There is no unique answer to your question as it's pretty much opinion-based, so I'm voting to close this.

Comment: Git isn't particularly relevant: whatever source control system you use has the same issues.

Comment: I agree with @GuerricP. Depending on your situation, you may try things like GitHub Actions or GitLab CI/CD, which helps you automatically build your project every time you commit a change and (again depending on your situation) you might even automatically push the resulted build into registry (like npm or GitLab's registries), where you can find the package and install it with tool like npm.